# Why is Apache removing multiple slashes?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This RewriteRule

`RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ test.php?url=$1`

On this URL

`mysite.com/test//one///two////three///`

Is giving me this result

`$1=url='one/two/three/'`

I'm using easyphp if it matters and I like to know **why is Apache removing multiple slashes internally without redirecting to correcred URL? and how can I disable or add a redirect to this behaviour?**

Thank in advance

Comment: Whilst multiple slashes are collapsed in the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_, you can still access the full URL (with additional slashes) by using the `%{REQUEST_URI}` server variable in a `RewriteCond` directive. See this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561645/htaccess-rewrite-removes-trailing-slashes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems multiple slashes are against the standard. As pointed out in [this post](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/546794-how-prevent-double-slashes-urls-being-replaced), [RFC 1630](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1630.txt) says:

> PATH
>
> The rest of the URI follows the colon in a format depending on the
>        scheme. The path is interpreted in a manner dependent on the
>         protocol being used.  However, when it contains slashes, these
>         ust imply a hierarchical structure.

`///` does not imply a hierarchical structure - you'd have empty folder names. From that I would guess that Apache's behaviour is by design. (Nor would it be a good idea to use multiple slashes, as the result would be an invalid URL).

I would use a different character instead.

Comment: Thanks. and doesn't this behavior make duplicate content if a search engine follows a multiple slashed link from another site to mine?

Comment: @Drust I would expect that Google fixes the link as well, but I can't say for sure. But if Apache fixes it with a 301, I think Google should understand

Comment: @Pekka웃 well, `Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)` do not gives a `301` redirect (in that case google will merge all urls with `///` to one correct URL). Instead, it looks like Apache rewrites requested URI, so if request is `GET /test/// HTTP/1.1`, then `REQUEST_URI` will be `test/`. I think it is bad, because I want to have full requested URI to my script, which will handle it... Still searching for a solution.

Comment: Note that [`MergeSlashes OFF`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mergeslashes) disables this behaviour.