# Apache mod_rewrite ignores periods and extra slashes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[0-9]+(/)?$ /hello.php [R=301]
```

localhost/123 redirects to localhost/hello.php as expected.

But:
localhost/123.... and localhost////123//// also redirect to localhost/hello.php.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the problem with periods. As for the slashes, however, if they do not create a hierarchical structure, Apache will just behave as if there is only one slash. So `////123///` becomes `/123/`. (see [Stack Overflow - Why is Apache removing multiple slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699542/why-is-apache-removing-multiple-slashes)). I will recommend that you change the rewrite to the following since you have no need to capture the slash for reuse.

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]+/?$ /hello.php [L,R=301]
```

If you decide you want to eliminate the trailing slashes all together, here's that possibility as well:

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]+$ /hello.php [L,R=301]
```