# Htaccess rewrite removes trailing slashes

Tags: php, .htaccess

Htaccess somehow automatically romoves all trailing slashes at the end of an url and keeps only one.

For example http://localhost/api/param1/// becomes http://localhost/api/param1/

Can you please tell me why this happens and how to get rid of this? The (.*) should match everything right? But it does not. Like I said, if I go to http://localhost/api/param1/// the `$_GET['url']` should be `param1///` but it is `param1/`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The `-d` & `-f` rewrite to directory and file location. `param1/` can be a directory, `param1///` can't be a directory.

Comment: Hmm, so you are saying that this is not possible? Now I am using $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] variable and it does the job but I am wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: Whilst you can resolve this in .htaccess by using the `REQUEST_URI` variable in a `RewriteCond` directive, using the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` superglobal (as you have done) in PHP is arguably just as good (or better) - perhaps depends on your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache automatically strips multiple slashes into a single slash in `RewriteRule` pattern.

If you want to capture multiple slashes use a `RewriteCond` instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ index.php?url=%1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. However it matches the whole URI not just the URI from the subfolder that the .htaccess file is in. But this is acceptable for me.

Comment: Yes `%{REQUEST_URI}` matches full URI not relative from current path.